# How do I pass variables to a middleware function? [SLIM Framework]

Tags: php, frameworks, routes, slim, middleware

I'm trying to pass the database variable to a middleware function. However I'm getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Slim\Route::prepare() in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/website/models/feedback.php on line 11 with
>   the code: "$results = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO ... "

The code is the following:

```
function newsletter(){

  $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
  $route = $app->request->post('route');
  $email = $app->request->post('email_subscribe');
  $subscribe = $app->request->post("subscribe");
  $oFeedback = new Feedback();
  if(!empty($email)) {
    $cleanEmail = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $type="newsletter";
    $oFeedback->saveFeedback($db,NULL,$cleanEmail,NULL,$type);
  }
}
```

And I'm calling the middleware function in the route like this:

```
$app->post('/triparticle', 'newsletter', function() use($app, $db){
})->name("triparticle_post");
```

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this with an anonymus function.

Your code could look like this:

```
$newsletter = function ($db){
    return function () use ($db){

      $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
      $route = $app->request->post('route');
      $email = $app->request->post('email_subscribe');
      $subscribe = $app->request->post("subscribe");
      $oFeedback = new Feedback();
      if(!empty($email)) {
        $cleanEmail = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $type="newsletter";
        $oFeedback->saveFeedback($db,NULL,$cleanEmail,NULL,$type);
      }
    };
};

$app->post('/triparticle', $newsletter($db), function(){
})->name("triparticle_post");
```

This is described [here](http://docs.slimframework.com/routing/middleware/).

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass vars directly to a middleware. 
With your call, you call an empty function with that vars.
But you can nest vars into your $app and get it from there inside your middleware.

Comment: Your answer would be more helpful if you could show an example of nesting variables in $app and how these variables can then be accessed inside the middleware.